# Cannot install intermediate SSL certificate

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, openssl

So i've got this LAMP server running on ubuntu 12.04 with an SSL certificate installed. I've got the certificate and the .ca-bundle files in /etc/ssl/certs. The host file located in /etc/apache2/sites-available called "default-ssl" has the following options in it;

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/bundle.ca-bundle
```

However my browser still doens't reckonize the intermediate certificate located in the bundle.ca-bundle file.

Please help me!

UPDATE: Got it figured out; had to edit the file 000-default located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and point it to the bundle.ca-bundle file.

Comment: Step 2 on [this](http://www.trustis.com/pki/fpsia/guide/ssl-server/cert-install/apache_mod_ssl.htm) page might help.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your link. Got it figured out; had to edit the 000-default file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and point it to the bundle.ca-bundle file.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: Please make an answer of your solution.

Comment: Yes, i have to wait 8 hours to make my own answer. Ill update it as soon as i can.

Comment: @Martijn Did not deliver on promised answer :<